Group by using str_detect for groups with similar strings
Consider this example data:
library(tidyverse)

dt <- tibble(Poison = c('Arsenic', 'Arsenic in Wine', 'Cyanide', 'Cyanide and Sugar'),
             Result = c('Death', 'Death With Class', 'Death', 'Death'))

I want to create a column that gives each group an identification number. However, I want the poisons to be grouped together by a string detection, i.e., 'Arsenic' and 'Arsenic in Wine' to be one group and 'Cyanide' and 'Cyanide and Sugar' to be another group. Currently, R thinks that each group is it's own, as such:
dt <- dt %>%
  group_by(Poison) %>%
  mutate(Group = n())

# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   Poison [4]
  Poison            Result           Group
  <chr>             <chr>            <int>
1 Arsenic           Death                1
2 Arsenic in Wine   Death With Class     1
3 Cyanide           Death                1
4 Cyanide and Sugar Death                1

I want it to be so that 'Arsenic' and 'Arsenic in Wine' is Group 1, and 'Cyanide', and 'Cyanide and Sugar' is Group 2. Any ideas?

Forgot the other half of the dataframe, added it in!

Do you know ahead of time all of the groups? That is, do you have (somewhere) c("Arsenic", "Cyanide")?

A combination of case_when and grepl could be useful:
dt %>% 
  mutate(Group = case_when(
    grepl("Arsenic", Poison) ~ 1,
    grepl("Cyanide", Poison) ~ 2
  ))
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Poison            Result           Group
  <chr>             <chr>            <dbl>
1 Arsenic           Death                1
2 Arsenic in Wine   Death With Class     1
3 Cyanide           Death                2
4 Cyanide and Sugar Death                2

If you don't want to write down any poisson, this could be useful:
dt %>% 
  mutate(Group = sub(" .*", "", Poison) %>% 
           as.factor %>% 
           as.integer())


I definitely don't want to write down the poisons, so thank you for that caveat! Works great, thanks so much!

If we know ahead of time a vector of "shortest patterns",
vec <- c("Arsenic", "Cyanide")
### or perhaps this for an automated approach
vec <- unique(sub(" .*", "", dt$Poison))

then we can do:
dt |>
  mutate(grp = apply(sapply(vec, grepl, Poison), 1, function(z) which(z)[1]))
# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#   Poison            Result             grp
#   <chr>             <chr>            <int>
# 1 Arsenic           Death                1
# 2 Arsenic in Wine   Death With Class     1
# 3 Cyanide           Death                2
# 4 Cyanide and Sugar Death                2


Use code with caution! ie small to medium dataset. Huge dataset won't work as adist creates a n by n matrix of the Poison column. ie comparing one element to the rest.
dt %>%
  mutate(group = (!adist(Poison, partial = TRUE)) %>%
           igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix()%>%
           igraph::components()%>%
           getElement('membership'))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Poison            Result           group
  <chr>             <chr>            <dbl>
1 Arsenic           Death                1
2 Arsenic in Wine   Death With Class     1
3 Cyanide           Death                2
4 Cyanide and Sugar Death                2


If at all you have the vector of needed groups you could do:
vec <- c("Arsenic", "Cyanide")
transform(dt, group = max.col(-t(adist(vec, Poison, partial = TRUE))))

             Poison           Result group
1           Arsenic            Death     1
2   Arsenic in Wine Death With Class     1
3           Cyanide            Death     2
4 Cyanide and Sugar            Death     2


If there is duplication in Poison, you could use unique(Poison) externally before using inside the larger dataset.

@r2evans Thats correct. whereby you will end up merging/joining the groups to the dataset

See if this works with your data set. It first splits the strings and then compares each element to see if a match exists. Working with a slightly more complex example.
library(dplyr)

tibble(dt, grp = sapply(strsplit(dt$Poison, " "), \(x)
  paste(unique(unlist(lapply(x, \(y) 
    which(grepl(paste0("\\b", y, "\\b"), dt$Poison))))), collapse="")))
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  Poison              Result           grp  
  <chr>               <chr>            <chr>
1 Arsenic             Death            12   
2 Arsenic A in Wine   Death With Class 125  
3 Cyanide             Death            345  
4 Cyanide and Sugar   Death            345  
5 Cyanide and Sugar A Death            3452

output using your data set
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Poison            Result           grp  
  <chr>             <chr>            <chr>
1 Arsenic           Death            12   
2 Arsenic in Wine   Death With Class 12   
3 Cyanide           Death            34   
4 Cyanide and Sugar Death            34

Data
dt <- structure(list(Poison = c("Arsenic", "Arsenic A in Wine", "Cyanide", 
"Cyanide and Sugar", "Cyanide and Sugar A"), Result = c("Death", 
"Death With Class", "Death", "Death", "Death")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

